# How to specify the type of class properties from a base class in a child class in TS?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types

I have the following code:

```
class Base {
    protected collection: ICollection<object>

    public constructor(collection: ICollection<object>) {
        this.collection = collection
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    public constructor(collection: ICollection<User>) {
        super(collection)
    }

    private foo(): void {
        // working with collection
    }
}
```

Although I specified a concrete type of the collection items in the constructor (User), when I work on the collection inside `foo()`, typescript thinks that I'm still working with the collection of type `ICollection<object>`, not with `ICollection<User>`. Currently I'm using a workaround like this inside `foo()`

```
const _collection = this.collection as ICollection<User>
```

But its obviously a bad idea to do it in every method.
How can I specify in the `Child` class that the property `collection` is of type `ICollection<User>`? Or should I simply override the property of the base class? It seems also as not the best idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution that exploits a type parameter:

```
class Base<B extends object> {
    protected collection: ICollection<B>

    public constructor(collection: ICollection<B>) {
        this.collection = collection
    }
}

class Child extends Base<User> {
    public constructor(collection: ICollection<User>) {
        super(collection)
    }

    private foo(): void {
        this.collection; // <-- has type ICollection<User> 
    }
}
```